# clearInterval in function

Tags: function, clearinterval

I'm trying to set and clear intervals for a carousel with two functions: `playX` and `stopX`.

```
var timerX; 

function playX (timerX, B, C, D, E) {    
setInterval(function() { away(timerX, B, C, D, E); },3000);  
}

function stopX (timerX, B, C, D, E) {  
clearInterval(timerX);   
console.log('STOP: CLEARED: timer: '+timerX);
}
```

Although it starts, and goes on and on, it doesn't stop, despite the function  being called:

```
Console:STOP: CLEARED: timer: timerX
```

I understand that the timer var has to be outside the functions, and it is and is not re-assigned anywhere else. Even so, it doesn't work.

I've looked at a number of questions here around this issue, but none have answers which help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `setInterval` should be used as an argument to `clearInterval`.

```js
var timerX; 
var intervalId;

function playX(timerX, B, C, D, E) {    
  intervalId = setInterval(function() { away(timerX, B, C, D, E); }, 3000);  
}

function stopX(timerX, B, C, D, E) {  
  clearInterval(intervalId);   
  console.log('STOP: CLEARED: timer: '+timerX);
}
```

Comment: Hi David,  Exactly what I needed. I'd tried many variations, but hadn't considered getting at the variable in this manner. Many thanks PB Note - I'll mark this as accepted when the icon appears.